# Can't return value from function in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to return a value called 'html' from a python function:

```
def loop_accounts(account_name, interactive): 
    regions = set_regions(account_name)
    aws_env_list = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'account_names_list', 'aws_kiki_page-' + today + '.csv')
    # Set the output file
    output_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list', 'csv', '')
    if interactive == 1:
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-instance-list-' + account_name + '-' + today +'.csv')
        output_file_name = 'aws-instance-list-' + account_name + '-' + today + '.csv'
    else:
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.csv')
        output_file_name = 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.csv'
        htmlfile, htmlfile_name, remove_htmlfile = convert_csv_to_html_table(output_file, today, interactive, account_name)
        with open(htmlfile, 'r') as htmlfile:
            html = htmlfile.read()
    return html
```

But python isn't seeing the value html when I try to return it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 657, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 631, in main
    html, htmlfile, output_file, output_file_name, remove_htmlfile = loop_accounts(aws_env_list, interactive, fieldnames, all_accounts_question)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 594, in loop_accounts
    return html, htmlfile, output_file, output_file_name, remove_htmlfile
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'html' referenced before assignment
```

Why is python not seeing this value called html? How can I return it?

Comment: What if `interactive==1`?? `html` doesn't exist

Comment: Looking at the traceback, I have the feeling that the error is coming from elsewhere, namely this section: `return html, htmlfile, output_file, output_file_name, remove_htmlfile` which is completely different from your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html` doesn't exist when `interactive==1`.

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to create `html` before the `if else` statement

Comment: Ok, if I set `html` to `None` at the start of the function, will I return the actual value of `html` when I set it in the else of `if interactive == 1`?

Comment: yes! You can modify the variable `html` inside the `else` statement. Instead, if you enter the `if` statement, teh function would return `None`.